# Store id global hash as keys

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I need all xml id stored hash as key and values is always empty. How can I collect all id values store in global hash in twig.

xml:

xml:

```
<book>
<book-meta>
<p><xref id="page_xii"/> to reproduce their work<xref id="fn1"/> in this volume<xref id="fn2"/>.</p>
</book-meta>
</book>
```

script:

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;
my $xml_twig_content = XML::Twig->new(
                keep_encoding => 1,
                twig_handlers => {
                keep_atts_order => 1,
                },
                pretty_print => 'indented',
);

$xml_twig_content->parsefile('sample.xml');
```

I can't do this, How can I get all ids a global hash as keys.

I need:

```
my %global;
```

1. page_xii
2. fn1
3. fn2

How can I get this. store a example this type, $global{page_xii} = '';

Comment: Can you post your twig? All I can see is the initializing code right now

Comment: @Zaid I don't think he had one.

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you need tham in order, in an array, or not, in a hash.

To get them in a hash, there is not much to do, they are in `$twig->{twig_id_list}` (why do you call the twig `$xml_twig_content`? It's long and cumbersome). This is not garanteed by the API, but it hasn't changed in over 10 years and I see no reason for it to change in the next 10.

To get them in an array, you can set a handler on `@*[@id]` that will push the id into the array:

```
twig_handlers => { '*[@id]' => sub { push @ids, $_->id; } }
```

then if what you want is a hash id => , do

```
my %global= map { $_ => $ids[$_] } 1..@ids;
```

It's kind of a weird requirement though.

Comment: I think it's amazing that there always is more than one solution to all the Twig questions. It's as if it was Perl. ;-)

Comment: to be honest XML::Twig is probably more like PHP: lots and lots of methods, with long and sometimes confusing names, but in the end it seems to get the job done (not that I have ever used PHP, mind you). It's also been around for nearly as long (the first, pre-CPAN, version is from 1997)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a handler for `_all_` elements that just parses out the `id` of each element like this. See the [docs](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) for more infos. You might need to search in it a bit.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
my $xml = <<'XML';
<book>
<book-meta>
<p><xref id="page_xii"/> to reproduce their work<xref id="fn1"/> in this volume<xref id="fn2"/>.</p>
</book-meta>
</book>
XML

my %global;
my $xml_twig_content = XML::Twig->new(
  keep_encoding => 1,
  twig_handlers => {
    keep_atts_order => 1,
    '_all_'         => sub {     # this is the important part!
      my ( $twig, $elem ) = @_;  # second argument is the current element
      $global{ $elem->id } = ''; # it has a method id() that gets the id
    },
  },
  pretty_print => 'indented',
);

$xml_twig_content->parse($xml);
print Dumper \%global;
```

---

On a more general note, you should add `use warnings` to your program. Furthermore, you'd usually not just set the elements' values in `%global` to `''`, but use an increment instead:

```
$global{ $elem->id }++;
```